# EVGA GTX 780 Superclocked stuck on 3D clock on idle?

Tags: windows-7, graphics-card, nvidia-graphics-card

I recently purchased parts and upgraded my main desktop computer. My current setup includes a GTX 780, I5 4670k CPU, an ASUS Z87-C motherboard, and 16gb of ram. After downloading EVGA Precision X and comparing clock speeds with a friend, we noticed that both his card and another friend's appear to downclock to somewhere in the 350MHZ on idle. Mine, on the other hand, stays at 692 MHZ.

I've been doing research and can't seem to find any solutions to the problem. He claims he didn't configure anything and the settings are all default. Why is my card not switching to 2D clock on idle like his?

#### Notes

- I am running Razer Synapse. I've tried killing it, but it had no apparent effect.
- Tried disabling hardware acceleration in all relevant browsers.
- Set power management profile to adaptive in NVIDIA control panel.
- I've only set my FPS target to 120 in EVGA Precision X. No other settings have been configured.
- I'm running dual monitors. My main display is a 1920x1080 144hz Asus VG248QE, my secondary display is a 60hz 1920x1080 HP monitor.

#### Current card (stuck on 3D clock at desktop on idle):

[image: Current Clock]

#### 2D Clocked Card (not mine, what I'm trying to achieve/what should be happening):

[image: Underclock]

Comment: Unless you have the exact same card it's unlikely you will be able to so what you want.  If I were to simply guess you purchased an overclocked card

Comment: @Ramhound All three of us purchased the exact same [model](http://www.evga.com/Products/Product.aspx?pn=03G-P4-2784-KR).

Comment: @Ramhound Plus it overclocks when running games or GPU intensive applications. 692 MHZ isn't nearly the max GPU clock it reaches. It's just that 692 MHZ appears to be the lowest it's reaching on idle, which shouldn't be the case.

Comment: The only thing I can think of is the other systems are supplying less power then you are to the card.  Actually I know thats the case.  Its also possible you just have a really high quality GPU it happens.  Honestly the fact his card is underclocked means he configured something.

Comment: @Ramhound: Edited with further relevant information. Once again, the problem isn't that my graphics card is "higher quality". We're all running the same model. It's staying stuck at a higher clock/3D clock at my desktop on idle and I've no idea why. This shouldn't be the case.

Comment: I actually do understand the question.  I am just pointing out that you are supplying more voltage which means the idle clock would be higher.  Have you overclock any other part of your system?  You can overclock the PCI-E.

Answer (score 1):

try setting the main monitor down to 120hz from 144hz. that fixed the throttling problem for me. i have a secondary 60hz monitor as well. I think it has something to do with 144hz + 60hz being wierd and 120hz + 60hz is more in sync.